# processing submit-action after "onsubmit-event"

Tags: jquery, events, submit, action

I am using this little jquery for an ajax-request with a php-script, which checks the input of a textfield:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var username = $("#username-field").val();
    if(username) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkinput.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 0) {
                    alertify.alert( data.error );
                } 
                if(data.result == 1) {
                    $("#submit")[0].submit();
                }
            }
        });
    } else { 
        alertify.alert( "You forgot to type username" );
    }
  });
});




<form action="" method="POST">

Username:
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." id="username-field">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send">

</form>
```

What i want:

If the returned "data.result" == "0", then display the alert-message and stay on page(no refresh)

If the returned "data.result" == "1", then process the submit-action.

I used preventDefault to stop this submit-action and the second if-clause to process the submit-action, but it doesnt work...anybody could help me?
greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id for `<form id="myform" action="your page name" method="POST" >`

use,

```
$("#myform").submit();
```

instead of

```
$("#submit")[0].submit();
```

Comment: ok most of it works now, thanks, but: if the returned data.result==0, there is no alert-message displased but the page is refreshed, why? how can i solve this?

Comment: May be the reason for `alertify` for testing can use `alert` and test you got the alert else can update the console.log error here

Comment: Add `return false;` in end of the statment and check